# How to get all user in django template without using views.py?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-messages

I have an existing project that has no views.py and models.py.It has a user login system.I want to get the list of all user in the template.I have searched more but found no solution.

Comment: https://github.com/mgaby25/django-postman-sample this the app that I want to use.

Comment: If there is no `views.py`, then you will have to create it.

Answer (score 0):

If you for some reason don't want views.py, you can create custom template tag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def user_list():
    return '<br>'.join([str(u) for u in get_user_model().objects.all()])
```